# C# arrays use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, variables, random

Here in this piece of code I'm trying to add random numbers between 0 to 9, to an array but when I'm trying to assign numbers to the array inside a for loop, I receive this error:

> Error 1   Use of unassigned local variable 'x'

Here is the code:

```
using System;
    class Core
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] x;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                x[i] = rnd.Next(1, 9);
            }
         }
     }
```

I've read MSDN description for the [Compiler Error CS0165](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx) but it does not talk about arrays.

Comment: To add to Darren's answer, you have to indicate the size of the array. You can't just add to it like a list.

Comment: Please check out my edit and consider something similar for your future questions. Showing an effort to solve problem yourself makes it for much better questions. Note that is you actually would read the description of error message you'd immediately try following search http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+initialize+array which could have given you even more information.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialise and assign a size to your array.

```
int[] x = new int[4];
```